# Spring Data JPA returning column from UPDATE @Query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Consider following scenario (transformed from real world example) were I have pre generated references in DB what I need to assign to users.

So my DB structure would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reference
(
    reference_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    group_id     INT NOT NULL,
    assigned_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    username     VARCHAR(256)
)
```

My repository looks something like this

```
@Repository
public interface ReferenceRepository extends JpaRepository<Reference, String> {
    
    @Query(
            value = "UPDATE reference " +
                    "SET username    = ?2, " +
                    "    assigned_at = now() " +
                    "WHERE reference_id = ( " +
                    "    SELECT reference_id " +
                    "    FROM reference " +
                    "    WHERE username IS NULL " +
                    "      AND group_id = ?1 " +
                    "    LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) " +
                    "RETURNING reference_id;"
            nativeQuery = true)
    String assignReference(int groupId, String userName);
```

Currently it works fine (this is invoked from @Transactional service), but I am just wondering is it valid use of @Query or it might cause some errors that I cannot see currently.

Answer (score 0):

This might be highly database and driver specific, but otherwise I don't see a real problem.

As to why this is database/driver specific:

- Since you are using a `@Query` annotation without `@Modifying` the query will get executed just like a select statement if this works or not is a question of how the driver is written. But I wouldn't expect that to change without notice since I would expect the authors to implement it this way by accident.
- I'm actually surprised, that a `FOR UPDATE` works in a subselect. This might not be the case for all databases. Anyway the syntax alone is database dependent AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Blaze-Persistence which is a library that lives on top of JPA/Hibernate: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#returning-clause-support

Your query with the query builder API of Blaze-Persistence would look like the following:

```
List<Long> ids = criteriaBuilderFactory.update(entityManager, Reference.class, "r")
    .set("username", userName)
    .setExpression("assignedAt", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    .where("r.id").in()
        .from(Reference.class, "rSub")
        .select("rSub.id"))
        .where("rSub.username").isNull()
        .where("rSub.group.id").eq(groupId)
        .setMaxResults(1)
    .end()
    .executeWithReturning("id", Long.class);
```

Unfortunately the locking in the subquery can't be modeled yet with Blaze-Persistence, but the rest of the query will look like what you anticipated.

Not sure if you are using PostgreSQL, but in that case you could use advisory locks which are available as functions which can be used in subqueries as well.